# Increment one of two variables randomly by one

Tags: javascript, html

Given two variables:

```
var counter1 = 0;
var counter2 = 0;
```

at the press of a button how can i make one of them increment its value by one?

Comment: counter1+=1 on click event!!

Comment: so pick one randomly and add one.... Do you know how to add a click event? Do you know how to make a random number? do you know how to use if/else? Do you know how to add one to a number? If you answered yes to all, than you have the basic steps.

Comment: I see what you mean epascarello,going to try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should add 1 point to one of the 2 random numbers

```js
var count1 = 0;
var count2 = 0;


function randomIncrement() {
  if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
    count1 +=1;
    console.log("count1 = " + count1);
  } else {
    count2 +=1;
    console.log("count2 = " + count2);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="randomIncrement();">Click me :D</button>
```

Comment: it works, this is just what i was looking for, thanks! =)

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
if(Math.random > 0.5){
    counter1 += 1;
} else {
    counter2 += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that will increment counter1 when a button with id myButton is clicked:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
    counter1++;
});
```